# Solaris tar: "symbolic link failed: Not a directory"

Tags: solaris, symlink, tar, archive

When unpacking a tar archive with a symlink under Solaris 10, I get this error:

```
tar: lib/jre/: symbolic link failed: Not a directory
```

The `lib/jre` symlink points to `lib/jre1.8.0_46` which is in the tar archive as well. I can unpack the tar just fine with GNU tar. So what's the problem here?

Comment: Obviously Solaris tar is not like Gnu tar. Aren't there any hints on the Solaris man page for tar?

Comment: *So what's the problem here?*  [GNU tar is not POSIX-compliant.](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/tar/html_node/tar_6.html)  By default it does not make standard-compliant archives.  See also ftp://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/tar/html_node/tar_113.html#SEC108 and ftp://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/tar/html_node/tar_117.html#SEC112

Comment: On some of the Solaris systems I've worked on `tar` has been aliased to `gtar`. Don't know if it was a good idea really, but never seen any problems with it. Also: The fact that it is actually GNU tar and not Solaris' tar which is dis-respecting the standard is of less importance to most people as GNU has in many ways become a de-facto standard.

Comment: Can you tell us the exact command line you are using to extract the tar archive?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Sure: `gunzip -c foo.tar.gz | tar -xvf -`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the gnu tar under Solaris. Then see inline:

- Solaris 10: check if you have it by doing `pkginfo SUNWgtar`
  Usual path is: `/usr/sfw/bin/gtar`
- Solaris 11: check if you have it by doing `pkg info gnu-tar`
  Usual path is `/usr/gnu/bin/tar` with two symlinks to`/usr/sfw/bin/gtar` and `/usr/bin/gtar`

Updating the info according to the comment. 
In case gnu tar is not available, you can create tar POSIX compliant with `--format=posix` option.

this is available from GNU tar version 1.14. More info can be found at [GNU TAR](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/tar.html#SEC145)

Comment: Ok, so our customer does not have GNU tar and cannot install it. In the future I will make sure that I use Solaris tar instead. BUT: is it possible to create a Solaris tar compatible file using GNUT tar?

Comment: please check the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you get the error `Not a directory`, it is obvious that the symlink in the tar archive is

```
lib/jre/ -> lib/jre1.8.0_46
```

which is different from what you tell us in your text.

If `gtar` does not complain about that link, it is broken.

Unfortunately, you did not give sufficient information about your constraints.

We need to know:

- what type of tar archive are you talking about. You get the type via `star -t -print-artype < foo.tar.gz`
- what is the exact entry in the archive. You get the answer via `star -tv < foo.tar.gz pat='*jre*'`

Archives created with `gtar` are not POSIX compliant and may even change the archive type in the middle of the archive. You should understand that this may have really strange results.

To get `star`, I recommend to fetch the latest `schilytools` from: https://sourceforge.net/projects/schilytools/files/ and compile them.